# Search for field with text overlap in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, replace

I have an interesting mysql issue.

I have a field X in a database containing the following text: "The fox ran through the woods, and he jumped over the moon."

I have a string x : "he jumped over the moon. He was happy."

I want to search the database field X to see if any entry overlaps the string x. If there is an overlap, I want to update the field X to : "The fox ran through the woods, and he jumped over the moon. He was happy."

How can I do this in a non-expensive way? I've though about using LIKE and IN but nothing immediately comes to mind.

-Sneha

Comment: There is no easy non-expensive way to do this. What you are looking for is 'fuzzy search', and MySQL doesn't support that natively (nor should it). It's a relatively advanced subject even to implement this intelligently, as it requires some custom algorithm to determine what an overlap is: in your simplified example, why doesn't the match already occur on the 2nd character, as it also spells `he`? Assuming you only want end-to-start overlaps, you would still need to determine dynamically when there is enough overlap and where.

Comment: What defines an overlap?  Technically if the beginning `h` exists in the database, then you'd have an overlap...